# Pythonic way to filter columns and then create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlsx file that I am opening with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(open('file.xlsx','rb'))
df['Description'].head
```

and I have the following result, which looks pretty good.

```
ID     | Description
:----- | :-----------------------------
0      | Some Description with no hash
1      | Text with #one hash
2      | Text with #two #hashes
```

Now I want to create a new column, keeping only words started with #, like this one:

```
ID     | Description                      |  Only_Hash
:----- | :-----------------------------   |  :-----------------
0      | Some Description with no hash    |   Nan
1      | Text with #one hash              |   #one
2      | Text with #two #hashes           |   #two #hashes
```

I was able to count/separate lines with #:

```
descriptionWithHash = df['Description'].str.contains('#').sum()
```

but now I want to create the column like I described above. What is the easiest way to do that?

Regards!

PS: it is supposed to show a table format in the question but I can't figure out why it is showing wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new'] =  df['Description'].str.findall('(\#\w+)').str.join(' ')
print(df)
   ID                    Description           new
0   0  Some Description with no hash              
1   1            Text with #one hash          #one
2   2         Text with #two #hashes  #two #hashes
```

And for NaNs:

```
df['new'] = df['Description'].str.findall('(\#\w+)').str.join(' ').replace('',np.nan)
print(df)
   ID                    Description           new
0   0  Some Description with no hash           NaN
1   1            Text with #one hash          #one
2   2         Text with #two #hashes  #two #hashes
```

Comment: this solution is much more elegant !

Answer (score 5):

```
In [126]: df.join(df.Description
     ...:           .str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')
     ...:           .unstack(-1)
     ...:           .T.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' ')).T
     ...:           .to_frame(name='Hash'))
Out[126]:
   ID                    Description          Hash
0   0  Some Description with no hash           NaN
1   1            Text with #one hash          #one
2   2         Text with #two #hashes  #two #hashes
```